# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_Pro_API_34 has terminated in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried to upgrade emulator from Nexus 5 API 24 to Pixel 7 Pro API 34.
The first one have worked well but new one is not work and display this error.

How can I fix this error?
I think that is caused by JDK version, is it right? If it is right, How can I config this setting?
I installed JDK 17.0.6 and 21

I tried to use Emulator with API 34 in Android Studio but this caused error.

Comment: Let me know your PC/Laptop specifications. Because that high-end emulator needs more CPUs (or GPUs) and RAMs to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a cold boot ?

If you are in Android Studio, launch the emulator using the Cold boot options from the three dotted menu right next to the start button.

if you are using the cmd to launch the emulator [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to use cold boot option, but the result was same.